# Usage of double "your" in "what is your favourite place in your hometown?"

Tags: pronouns

Is this question correct?

> what is **your** favourite place in **your** hometown?

It’s confusing because a double ‘your’ seems wrong

Comment: Yes, it's correct, because the first "your" refers to "place", the second "your" refers to "hometown".

Comment: Please include the question and example in the body of post. Use the title to ask a short version of the question or provide a brief description of the problem. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for tips and examples.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's fine.  It's completely natural to repeat pronouns in English, even if this seems odd in other languages.  A more extreme example:

> Brian, I've told you for the last time, get ready for school!  Get **your** shoes out of **your** closet and put them on **your** feet, then come down to have **your** breakfast. **Your** bus will be here in 20 minutes.

Side note: be aware that "favourite" is the BrE spelling of the word.  AmE spells it "favorite".

Answer (score 0):

The word "hometown" in this sentence is placing a limitation on the word "place". If I want to take you somewhere and I ask you what your favorite place is, you might be thinking of the entire universe and tell me that your favorite place is Neptune. I might then respond and ask you to limit your favorite place to somewhere on this planet. You might then tell me that your favorite place is Brasil. But that might still be too far away if we are in Romania. So I might then ask you for your favorite place in the country. We can continue going back and forth and limiting your choice of favorite place to ever smaller areas. One such small area would be "hometown".

But whose hometown am I referring to? There's **my** hometown, **his** hometown, **her** hometown, **their** hometown — there are so many possibilities, and you can have a favorite place in each of those locations, so I need to be more specific. So I tell you that I am referring specifically to **your** hometown.

So now when I ask you for "your favorite place in your hometown" I am placing three limitations on the place:

1. It should be **your** favorite place, not someone else's favorite place.
2. The favorite place can't be anywhere; I am limiting it to a specific geographical location, namely, a **hometown**.
3. And I am further limiting it to **your** hometown and not someone else's hometown.